# how to click a button if another element contains a text

Tags: python, appium, appium-android

I am testing an app and have a difficulty to click a button which another element contains a text as seen below.

[image]

I want to click on "DETAILS" button which has "UPCOMING" word above it.

I have tried to do it but none of it does the job.

**First**

```
for booking_card in context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*(@class='android.view.ViewGroup')"):
        if booking_card.text == "UPCOMING":
            context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'DETAILS')]").click()
```

**Second**

```
context.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'UPCOMING')]//*[@text='DETAILS']").click()
```

**Third**
I tried to find the details button using the parent, sibling and ancestor method but still failed.

```
//*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup']//*[contains(@text, 'UPCOMING')]/following-sibling::*[contains(@text, 'DETAILS')]
```

here is the Hierarchy of the elements:
[image]

I really appreciate any help, thank you.
If there's something else I need to explain, let me know.

Comment: try finding element from the bookingcard element `bookingcard.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'DETAILS')]).click()`

Comment: yeah mate, I tried that, but I think the appium will be confused which one should I click, because there are two buttons which contain the same word. thanks for the reply.

Comment: it should'nt be as long as youhave the if clause booking_card.text == "UPCOMING" but ive only used this in a web context not an app context

Comment: I tried to find it using parent, sibling or ancestor method but still failed, it looks like this //*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup']//*[contains(@text, 'UPCOMING')]/following-sibling::*[contains(@text, 'DETAILS')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer, so the way to do it is to use parent, following-sibling method.
all I did is to make sure the hierarchy of the elements are correct so that I can find what I was looking for.

here's the code that I have done, it's simple.

```
isPresent(context, MobileBy.XPATH, "//*[@text='UPCOMING']/parent::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup']/parent::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup']/following-sibling::*[@class='android.view.ViewGroup']//*[@text='DETAILS']").click()
```

so the way I did it, to look the 'UPCOMING' word first, and then I need to find the parent element and then click on the DETAILS button.